# Windows Batch - Find a line and replace with text

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, replace, find

probably this had been already answered in the Internet but I can't find the solution.

I've a .ini file which contains a lot of text, here is an example:

```
[General]
FullScreen = True
InternalResolution = 0
```

I need to setup a batch file that searchs for this line InternalResolution and changes the value for a different number, for example 5.
The output should look like this:

```
[General]
FullScreen = True
InternalResolution = 5
```

I have two problems, the first one is that the value = 0 sometimes could be = 1, or = 2, and also that all the spaces have to exist in the file (an app depends of this ini file so I can't remove the spaces.
I tried this:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:Variables
set InputFile=myfile.ini
set OutputFile=myfiletemp.ini
set "_strFind=InternalResolution = 0"
set "_strInsert=InternalResolution = 5"

:Replace
>"%OutputFile%" (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
    if "%%A" equ "%_strFind%" (echo %_strInsert%) else (echo %%A)
  )
)

DEL %InputFile%
MOVE %OutputFile% %InputFile%


ENDLOCAL
```

It works only if the InternalResolution value is 0. I don't know how to replace the line if the value is something different than 0. There should be a way to search if the line contains the text InternalResolution = X and replace the whole line or the value.

Thank you.

Comment: there doesn't seem to have an internal command that can alter the file in native cmd, you can only append data to it or rewrite it (unless you're talking about psh)

Comment: Trying to determine each possible value seems a little unnecessary, based upon what you've told us. Why don't you just use `find.exe`, to see if `InternalResolution = 5` is a match within `myfile.ini`, and if it isn't, just add/replace it.

Comment: You might skip the `del` command when adding the `/Y` switch to the `move` command line...

Answer (score 2):

`FIND` is a good option. An easier way is to separate it into two tokens `%%A` `%%B` and just test if `%%A` is equal to `%_strFind%` (i also changed it).

```
@echo off

:Variables
set InputFile=myfile.ini
set OutputFile=myfiletemp.ini
set "_strFind=InternalResolution"
set "_strInsert=InternalResolution = 5"

:Replace
>%OutputFile% (
  for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims= " %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
    if "%%A" equ "%_strFind%" (echo %_strInsert%) else (echo %%A %%B)
  )
)

MOVE /Y %OutputFile% %InputFile%
```

Tested on a Windows 10 laptop.
**NOTE: Might not be able to handle poisonous characters**

Comment: I'd add the `=`-sign to the list of delimiters, because the surrounding spaces in the might be optional...

Comment: @asc I tried for an hour to include the equal sign as a delimiter and settled for this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423960/8826818

Comment: I meant just using `for /F` option string `"usebackq tokens=1* delims== "`; but then `echo %%A %%B` needs to be replaced by `echo %%A = %%B`...

Comment: @asc I did that but it fails on `[General]` and `Full Screen = True`. General becomes `[General]=` and Full Screen becomes `Full Screen True`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html), like in the following:

```cmd
:Replace
> "%OutputFile%" (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
        set "line=%%A"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if "!line!" equ "%_strFind%!line:*%_strFind%=!" (
            echo(!_strInsert!
        ) else (
            echo(%%A
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.1

Replace text with PowerShell 5.1 using get-content and a regular expression.

There must be exactly one space before and after the equal sign.

`InternalResolution = 0-9` is replaced with `InternalResolution = 5`

```
(Get-Content "myfile.ini") -replace "InternalResolution = \d", "InternalResolution = 5" | Set-Content "myfiletemp.ini"
```

See [how to replace text with powershell, get-content,-replace, and regex](https://www.bing.com/search?q=how+to+replace+text+powershell+get-content+%22-replace%22+regex)

Regex

Comment: A desire to use cmd was not expressed.  No cmd tag was used.

Comment: Thank you guys! HackingAddict0302's method works awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit

Find and replace text with cmd's FOR and IF commands

Replaces:

```
InternalResolution = 0
InternalResolution      = 1
InternalResolution =      2
InternalResolution =      abc
```

With:

```
InternalResolution = whatever value you want
```

`InternalResolution= whatever` is not replaced.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set InputFile=myfile.ini
set FindStr=InternalResolution
copy /y %InputFile% %InputFile%.bak
(for /f "usebackq tokens=1*" %%g in ("%InputFile%") do if "%%g" equ "%FindStr%" (echo %%g = 5) else (echo %%g %%h))> %temp%\# 
MOVE /Y %temp%\# %InputFile%
```